# How can I automate this to run across all databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have this script to get SQL user audit info. This is a great script but I cannot seem to get it to run across all databases. I can't run this manually against each database as it would be too time consuming.

I have tried the sp_MSforeachdb approach but it fails at the SELECT statements.

Here is the script:

```
SELECT
   ServerName          = @@SERVERNAME,
   LoginName           = AccessSummary.LoginName,
   LoginType           = CASE WHEN syslogins.isntuser = 1 THEN 'WINDOWS_LOGIN' WHEN syslogins.isntgroup = 1 THEN 'WINDOWS_GROUP' ELSE 'SQL_USER' END,
   DatabaseName        = DB_NAME(),
   SelectAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.SelectAccess),
   InsertAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.InsertAccess),
   UpdateAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.UpdateAccess),
   DeleteAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.DeleteAccess),
   DBOAccess           = MAX(AccessSummary.DBOAccess),
   SysadminAccess      = MAX(AccessSummary.SysadminAccess)
FROM
   (
       /* Get logins with permissions */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysDatabasePrincipal.name,
           SelectAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = 'SELECT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           InsertAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = 'INSERT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           UpdateAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = 'UPDATE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DeleteAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = 'DELETE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DBOAccess           = 0,
           SysadminAccess      = 0
       FROM sys.database_permissions AS sysDatabasePermission
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipal
           ON sysDatabasePrincipal.principal_id = sysDatabasePermission.grantee_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipal
           ON sysServerPrincipal.sid = sysDatabasePrincipal.sid
       WHERE sysDatabasePermission.class_desc = 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN'
           AND sysDatabasePrincipal.type_desc IN ('WINDOWS_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_GROUP', 'SQL_USER')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.is_disabled = 0
       UNION ALL
       /* Get group members with permissions */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysDatabasePrincipalMember.name,
           SelectAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = 'SELECT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           InsertAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = 'INSERT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           UpdateAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = 'UPDATE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DeleteAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = 'DELETE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DBOAccess           = 0,
           SysadminAccess      = 0
       FROM sys.database_permissions AS sysDatabasePermission
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalRole
           ON sysDatabasePrincipalRole.principal_id = sysDatabasePermission.grantee_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members AS sysDatabaseRoleMember
           ON sysDatabaseRoleMember.role_principal_id = sysDatabasePrincipalRole.principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalMember
           ON sysDatabasePrincipalMember.principal_id = sysDatabaseRoleMember.member_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipal
           ON sysServerPrincipal.sid = sysDatabasePrincipalMember.sid
       WHERE sysDatabasePermission.class_desc = 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN'
           AND sysDatabasePrincipalRole.type_desc = 'DATABASE_ROLE'
           AND sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name <> 'public'
           AND sysDatabasePrincipalMember.type_desc IN ('WINDOWS_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_GROUP', 'SQL_USER')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.is_disabled = 0
       UNION ALL
       /* Get users in db_owner, db_datareader and db_datawriter */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysServerPrincipal.name,
           SelectAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN ('db_owner', 'db_datareader') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           InsertAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN ('db_owner', 'db_datawriter') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           UpdateAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN ('db_owner', 'db_datawriter') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DeleteAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN ('db_owner', 'db_datawriter') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DBOAccess           = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name = 'db_owner' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           SysadminAccess      = 0
       FROM sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalRole
       INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members AS sysDatabaseRoleMember
           ON sysDatabaseRoleMember.role_principal_id = sysDatabasePrincipalRole.principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalMember
           ON sysDatabasePrincipalMember.principal_id = sysDatabaseRoleMember.member_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipal
           ON sysServerPrincipal.sid = sysDatabasePrincipalMember.sid
       WHERE sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN ('db_owner', 'db_datareader', 'db_datawriter')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.type_desc IN ('WINDOWS_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_GROUP', 'SQL_LOGIN')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.is_disabled = 0
       UNION ALL
       /* Get users in sysadmin */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysServerPrincipalMember.name,
           SelectAccess        = 1,
           InsertAccess        = 1,
           UpdateAccess        = 1,
           DeleteAccess        = 1,
           DBOAccess           = 0,
           SysadminAccess      = 1
       FROM sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipalRole
       INNER JOIN sys.server_role_members AS sysServerRoleMember
           ON sysServerRoleMember.role_principal_id = sysServerPrincipalRole.principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipalMember
           ON sysServerPrincipalMember.principal_id = sysServerRoleMember.member_principal_id
       WHERE sysServerPrincipalMember.type_desc IN ('WINDOWS_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_GROUP', 'SQL_LOGIN')
           AND sysServerPrincipalMember.is_disabled = 0
   ) AS AccessSummary
INNER JOIN MASTER.dbo.syslogins AS syslogins
   ON syslogins.loginname = AccessSummary.LoginName
WHERE AccessSummary.LoginName NOT LIKE 'NT Service%'
GROUP BY
   AccessSummary.LoginName,
   CASE WHEN syslogins.isntuser = 1 THEN 'WINDOWS_LOGIN' WHEN syslogins.isntgroup = 1 THEN 'WINDOWS_GROUP' ELSE 'SQL_USER' END
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 36
Incorrect syntax near 'THEN'.

Comment: that probably because sp_MSforeachdb only allows fairly short commands @command1 nvarchar(2000)

Comment: with the SP approach you would need to script it into every DB...

Comment: trying to avoid that route since I have several hundred databases

Comment: you can automate the scripting too.  http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/create-stored-procedure-using-sp_msforeachdb-on-all-databases.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out.

```
DECLARE AllDatabases CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases

OPEN AllDatabases

DECLARE @DBNameVar NVARCHAR(128),@Statement NVARCHAR(MAX)

FETCH NEXT FROM AllDatabases INTO @DBNameVar
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
PRINT N'CHECKING DATABASE ' + @DBNameVar
SET @Statement = N'USE ' + @DBNameVar + CHAR(13)
+ N'SELECT
   ServerName          = @@SERVERNAME,
   LoginName           = AccessSummary.LoginName,
   LoginType           = CASE WHEN syslogins.isntuser = 1 THEN ''WINDOWS_LOGIN'' WHEN syslogins.isntgroup = 1 THEN ''WINDOWS_GROUP'' ELSE ''SQL_USER'' END,
   DatabaseName        = DB_NAME(),
   SelectAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.SelectAccess),
   InsertAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.InsertAccess),
   UpdateAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.UpdateAccess),
   DeleteAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.DeleteAccess),
   DBOAccess           = MAX(AccessSummary.DBOAccess),
   SysadminAccess      = MAX(AccessSummary.SysadminAccess)
FROM
   (
       /* Get logins with permissions */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysDatabasePrincipal.name,
           SelectAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''SELECT'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           InsertAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''INSERT'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           UpdateAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''UPDATE'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DeleteAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''DELETE'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DBOAccess           = 0,
           SysadminAccess      = 0
       FROM sys.database_permissions AS sysDatabasePermission
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipal
           ON sysDatabasePrincipal.principal_id = sysDatabasePermission.grantee_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipal
           ON sysServerPrincipal.sid = sysDatabasePrincipal.sid
       WHERE sysDatabasePermission.class_desc = ''OBJECT_OR_COLUMN''
           AND sysDatabasePrincipal.type_desc IN (''WINDOWS_LOGIN'', ''WINDOWS_GROUP'', ''SQL_USER'')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.is_disabled = 0
       UNION ALL
       /* Get group members with permissions */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysDatabasePrincipalMember.name,
           SelectAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''SELECT'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           InsertAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''INSERT'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           UpdateAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''UPDATE'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DeleteAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''DELETE'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DBOAccess           = 0,
           SysadminAccess      = 0
       FROM sys.database_permissions AS sysDatabasePermission
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalRole
           ON sysDatabasePrincipalRole.principal_id = sysDatabasePermission.grantee_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members AS sysDatabaseRoleMember
           ON sysDatabaseRoleMember.role_principal_id = sysDatabasePrincipalRole.principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalMember
           ON sysDatabasePrincipalMember.principal_id = sysDatabaseRoleMember.member_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipal
           ON sysServerPrincipal.sid = sysDatabasePrincipalMember.sid
       WHERE sysDatabasePermission.class_desc = ''OBJECT_OR_COLUMN''
           AND sysDatabasePrincipalRole.type_desc = ''DATABASE_ROLE''
           AND sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name <> ''public''
           AND sysDatabasePrincipalMember.type_desc IN (''WINDOWS_LOGIN'', ''WINDOWS_GROUP'', ''SQL_USER'')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.is_disabled = 0
       UNION ALL
       /* Get users in db_owner, db_datareader and db_datawriter */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysServerPrincipal.name,
           SelectAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN (''db_owner'', ''db_datareader'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           InsertAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN (''db_owner'', ''db_datawriter'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           UpdateAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN (''db_owner'', ''db_datawriter'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DeleteAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN (''db_owner'', ''db_datawriter'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DBOAccess           = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name = ''db_owner'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           SysadminAccess      = 0
       FROM sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalRole
       INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members AS sysDatabaseRoleMember
           ON sysDatabaseRoleMember.role_principal_id = sysDatabasePrincipalRole.principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalMember
           ON sysDatabasePrincipalMember.principal_id = sysDatabaseRoleMember.member_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipal
           ON sysServerPrincipal.sid = sysDatabasePrincipalMember.sid
       WHERE sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN (''db_owner'', ''db_datareader'', ''db_datawriter'')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.type_desc IN (''WINDOWS_LOGIN'', ''WINDOWS_GROUP'', ''SQL_LOGIN'')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.is_disabled = 0
       UNION ALL
       /* Get users in sysadmin */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysServerPrincipalMember.name,
           SelectAccess        = 1,
           InsertAccess        = 1,
           UpdateAccess        = 1,
           DeleteAccess        = 1,
           DBOAccess           = 0,
           SysadminAccess      = 1
       FROM sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipalRole
       INNER JOIN sys.server_role_members AS sysServerRoleMember
           ON sysServerRoleMember.role_principal_id = sysServerPrincipalRole.principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipalMember
           ON sysServerPrincipalMember.principal_id = sysServerRoleMember.member_principal_id
       WHERE sysServerPrincipalMember.type_desc IN (''WINDOWS_LOGIN'', ''WINDOWS_GROUP'', ''SQL_LOGIN'')
           AND sysServerPrincipalMember.is_disabled = 0
   ) AS AccessSummary
INNER JOIN MASTER.dbo.syslogins AS syslogins
   ON syslogins.loginname = AccessSummary.LoginName
WHERE AccessSummary.LoginName NOT LIKE ''NT Service%''
GROUP BY
   AccessSummary.LoginName,
   CASE WHEN syslogins.isntuser = 1 THEN ''WINDOWS_LOGIN'' WHEN syslogins.isntgroup = 1 THEN ''WINDOWS_GROUP'' ELSE ''SQL_USER'' END
'
EXEC sp_executesql @Statement
PRINT CHAR(13) + CHAR(13)
FETCH NEXT FROM AllDatabases INTO @DBNameVar
END

CLOSE AllDatabases
DEALLOCATE AllDatabases
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
DECLARE @DB_Name varchar(100)
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(max)

DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases

OPEN database_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


set @Command = 
'
use ' + @DB_Name + ';


SELECT
   ServerName          = @@SERVERNAME,
   LoginName           = AccessSummary.LoginName,
   LoginType           = CASE WHEN syslogins.isntuser = 1 THEN ''WINDOWS_LOGIN'' WHEN syslogins.isntgroup = 1 THEN ''WINDOWS_GROUP'' ELSE ''SQL_USER'' END,
   DatabaseName        = DB_NAME(),
   SelectAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.SelectAccess),
   InsertAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.InsertAccess),
   UpdateAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.UpdateAccess),
   DeleteAccess        = MAX(AccessSummary.DeleteAccess),
   DBOAccess           = MAX(AccessSummary.DBOAccess),
   SysadminAccess      = MAX(AccessSummary.SysadminAccess)
FROM
   (
       /* Get logins with permissions */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysDatabasePrincipal.name,
           SelectAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''SELECT'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           InsertAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''INSERT'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           UpdateAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''UPDATE'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DeleteAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''DELETE'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DBOAccess           = 0,
           SysadminAccess      = 0
       FROM sys.database_permissions AS sysDatabasePermission
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipal
           ON sysDatabasePrincipal.principal_id = sysDatabasePermission.grantee_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipal
           ON sysServerPrincipal.sid = sysDatabasePrincipal.sid
       WHERE sysDatabasePermission.class_desc = ''OBJECT_OR_COLUMN''
           AND sysDatabasePrincipal.type_desc IN (''WINDOWS_LOGIN'', ''WINDOWS_GROUP'', ''SQL_USER'')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.is_disabled = 0
       UNION ALL
       /* Get group members with permissions */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysDatabasePrincipalMember.name,
           SelectAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''SELECT'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           InsertAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''INSERT'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           UpdateAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''UPDATE'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DeleteAccess        = CASE WHEN permission_name = ''DELETE'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DBOAccess           = 0,
           SysadminAccess      = 0
       FROM sys.database_permissions AS sysDatabasePermission
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalRole
           ON sysDatabasePrincipalRole.principal_id = sysDatabasePermission.grantee_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members AS sysDatabaseRoleMember
           ON sysDatabaseRoleMember.role_principal_id = sysDatabasePrincipalRole.principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalMember
           ON sysDatabasePrincipalMember.principal_id = sysDatabaseRoleMember.member_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipal
           ON sysServerPrincipal.sid = sysDatabasePrincipalMember.sid
       WHERE sysDatabasePermission.class_desc = ''OBJECT_OR_COLUMN''
           AND sysDatabasePrincipalRole.type_desc = ''DATABASE_ROLE''
           AND sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name <> ''public''
           AND sysDatabasePrincipalMember.type_desc IN (''WINDOWS_LOGIN'', ''WINDOWS_GROUP'', ''SQL_USER'')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.is_disabled = 0
       UNION ALL
       /* Get users in db_owner, db_datareader and db_datawriter */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysServerPrincipal.name,
           SelectAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN (''db_owner'', ''db_datareader'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           InsertAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN (''db_owner'', ''db_datawriter'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           UpdateAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN (''db_owner'', ''db_datawriter'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DeleteAccess        = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN (''db_owner'', ''db_datawriter'') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           DBOAccess           = CASE WHEN sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name = ''db_owner'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
           SysadminAccess      = 0
       FROM sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalRole
       INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members AS sysDatabaseRoleMember
           ON sysDatabaseRoleMember.role_principal_id = sysDatabasePrincipalRole.principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS sysDatabasePrincipalMember
           ON sysDatabasePrincipalMember.principal_id = sysDatabaseRoleMember.member_principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipal
           ON sysServerPrincipal.sid = sysDatabasePrincipalMember.sid
       WHERE sysDatabasePrincipalRole.name IN (''db_owner'', ''db_datareader'', ''db_datawriter'')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.type_desc IN (''WINDOWS_LOGIN'', ''WINDOWS_GROUP'', ''SQL_LOGIN'')
           AND sysServerPrincipal.is_disabled = 0
       UNION ALL
       /* Get users in sysadmin */
       SELECT
           LoginName           = sysServerPrincipalMember.name,
           SelectAccess        = 1,
           InsertAccess        = 1,
           UpdateAccess        = 1,
           DeleteAccess        = 1,
           DBOAccess           = 0,
           SysadminAccess      = 1
       FROM sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipalRole
       INNER JOIN sys.server_role_members AS sysServerRoleMember
           ON sysServerRoleMember.role_principal_id = sysServerPrincipalRole.principal_id
       INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sysServerPrincipalMember
           ON sysServerPrincipalMember.principal_id = sysServerRoleMember.member_principal_id
       WHERE sysServerPrincipalMember.type_desc IN (''WINDOWS_LOGIN'', ''WINDOWS_GROUP'', ''SQL_LOGIN'')
           AND sysServerPrincipalMember.is_disabled = 0
   ) AS AccessSummary
INNER JOIN MASTER.dbo.syslogins AS syslogins
   ON syslogins.loginname = AccessSummary.LoginName
WHERE AccessSummary.LoginName NOT LIKE ''NT Service%''
GROUP BY
   AccessSummary.LoginName,
   CASE WHEN syslogins.isntuser = 1 THEN ''WINDOWS_LOGIN'' WHEN syslogins.isntgroup = 1 THEN ''WINDOWS_GROUP'' ELSE ''SQL_USER'' END
   '


     EXEC sp_executesql @Command

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name

END

CLOSE database_cursor
DEALLOCATE database_cursor
```